# express-socket.io-session session variables are not available

Tags: node.js, sockets, session, express

I am using express-socket.io-session module https://github.com/oskosk/express-socket.io-session

I can see the session data on socket.handshake

```
{
  headers: {
    host: 'xxxxxxx:8000',
    connection: 'Upgrade',
    pragma: 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    upgrade: 'websocket',
    origin: 'http://localhost:8000',
    'sec-websocket-version': '13',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTM L, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Safari/537.36',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,hi;q=0.6,id;q=0.4,ms;q=0.2'
  },
  time: 'Thu May 21 2015 17:06:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)',
  address: '::ffff:xxxxxxx',
  secret: undefined,
  cookies: {

  },
  signedCookies: {

  },
  sessionStore: {
    sessions: {
      'KK--EcvwVZieofM9NwG_Asee9VKPW8fn': '{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge ":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"_csrfSecret":"2Tr7DSbOEeXVOw= =","localeCountry":"US","experimentation":{"version":"1.0","treatments":[],"guid ":"764290c314d0a397ab134c29fe9bfc15"},"experimentationTimeStamp":1432208183650}'
    },
    generate: [
      Function
    ],
    _events: {
      disconnect: [
        Function
      ],
      connect: [
        Function
      ]
    }
  },
  sessionID: '6ZS-AMnOsha0FT_ALGrNp_-dp2Ji90yY',
  session: {
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      _expires: null,
      originalMaxAge: null,
      httpOnly: true
    }
  }
}
```

The socket.handshake.session doesn't have the session data.  I am unclear on how to extract the session data from socket.handshake.sessionStore

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, but isn't all of your session data right there in socket.handshake.sessionStore?
Session KK--EcvwVZieofM9NwG_Asee9VKPW8fn : .......

Comment: Yes. But as you can see the sessionStore has an object sessions which sets the session data to a dynamic key.  And the sessions object is not in itself a JSON.  The express-socket.io-session module shows examples in which the session data is accessed through socket.handshake.session.

Comment: I'm assuming that the key is the session ID? If so, then yes, this is will dynamic and therefore you will not be able to know it ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the session data is concerned, its JSON represented as a string. You can iterate over the keys in the root object and parse each key's value.

```
var keys = Object.keys(socket.handshake.sessionStore.sessions);
keys.forEach(function(key) {

    // extract string into a json object   
    var sessionObject = JSON.parse(socket.handshake.sessionStore.sessions[key]);

});
```